# SPARQL recursion: Get property of class, or parent class, or grand-parent class, etc

Tags: recursion, sparql, wikidata-query-service

- I have the [Grumpy Cat](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q7714263) Wikidata item, and I want to get the [icon](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2910) property of **the item it is an instance** of, which is [cat](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q146).
- If [cat](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q146) does not have an [icon](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2910), then I want the **icon of cat's parent class**, which is [domesticated animal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q622852).
- If [domesticated animal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q622852) does not have an [icon](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P2910), then I want the **icon of domesticated animal's parent class**, which is [animal](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q729)
- Etc, **recursively**, until an icon is found or until there is no parent class anymore.

How to get that in SPARQL?

In particular, if both cat and animal have icons, then I want to get cat's icon rather than animal's icon, because it is closer to Grumpy Cat.

If the item is an instance of several classes, or if a class is a sub-class of several classes, it would be great if all branches could be explored, and the closest icon chosen. Performance is quite important, I hope the query can run in less than a second on https://query.wikidata.org . I have tried writing a query based on imbricated MINUS clauses, but it is not really recursive.

If needed for test purposes, here are [many Wikidata items with icons](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23defaultView%3AImageGrid%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Ficon%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2910%20%3Ficon.%0A%09SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0ALIMIT%201000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't recursively look for something in SPARQL, and then stop when you find the first one. What you can do is either get all the icons, a random icon, or define a finite amount of classes that you go through.

You can use a chain of optionals to get the closest icon (in the case where you define a static depth):

```
# SAMPLE is used here because 1) the resource might have multiple classes,
# and 2) because of the fallback below
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?cls ?clsLabel (SAMPLE(?icon) AS ?icon) WHERE {
  BIND(wd:Q103474 AS ?item)
  ?item wdt:P31 ?cls.
  OPTIONAL { ?cls wdt:P2910 ?icon. }
  OPTIONAL { ?cls (wdt:P279/wdt:P2910) ?icon. }
  OPTIONAL { ?cls (wdt:P279/wdt:P279/wdt:P2910) ?icon. }
  OPTIONAL { ?cls (wdt:P279/wdt:P279/wdt:P279/wdt:P2910) ?icon. }
  # You can continue the optionals with longer property paths,
  # here we just fall back to trying the whole class path
  # (returning all icons in the path in an arbitrary order).
  OPTIONAL { ?cls (wdt:P279+/wdt:P2910) ?icon. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?cls ?clsLabel
```

The first successful optional will bind `?icon`, and so this variable will hold the "closest" icon. The `SAMPLE` will make sure the query only returns one icon.

Comment: Are you sure that the `OPTIONAL`s will always be tried from first to last? Is there zero risk that a dynamic optimizer would change the order? (I could imagine a learning optimizer that performs random changes just to see what's faster)

Comment: [According to the spec optionals are left-associative](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OptionalMatching). So no, the optimizer should not change the order.